# Best way to insert a number and adjust all numbers after it

Tags: javascript

I feel this is a basic problem but I am having a hard time coming up with a more elegant solution.

So my problem is that I have an array object with a field for Priority.

The priority would be sequential from 1 being the highest.

For example I have:

```
[{id: 1, priority: 1}, {id: 2, priority: 2}, {id: 3, priority: 3}]
```

Then I want to change the priority of id: 3 into 1 which the resulting array would be

```
[{id: 1, priority: 2}, {id: 2, priority: 3}, {id: 3, priority: 1}]
```

Right now my solution is looping the lenght of array starting with the Priority value that's going to be change and adding + 1. A lot of complication comes up with this approach and I feel I'm making it to complicated on what it should be

Comment: Can multiple items have the same priority? Is it okay to not use some priorities, or do you want them "dense"? Is the list supposed to be sorted by priority (both at the beginning and after the modification)?

Comment: No, the priorities needs to be sequential since it will be use for sorting on the table. On beginning it should be sorted then when it gets modified it will be sorted again

Comment: @FranzJustinBuenaventura I believe I've found a nice, clean solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An easy, if not necessarily completely efficient, solution would be to temporarily allow non-integer priorities, sort the list by priority, then renumber the priorities.

E.g. if you have

```
[
  { id: "a", priority: 1 },
  { id: "b", priority: 2 },
  { id: "c", priority: 3 },
]
```

and you'd need to add a `d` with a priority between `b` and `c`, you could temporarily assign it (2 + 3) / 2, i.e. `2.5`:

```
[
  { id: "a", priority: 1 },
  { id: "b", priority: 2 },
  { id: "c", priority: 3 },
  { id: "d", priority: 2.5 }
]
```

Then sort the list by `priority` (using whichever method you like), so you get

```
[
  { id: "a", priority: 1 },
  { id: "b", priority: 2 },
  { id: "d", priority: 2.5 }
  { id: "c", priority: 3 },
]
```

and then renumber the priorities with

```
itemsInPriorityOrder.forEach((item, index) => {
  item.priority = index + 1;
});
```

to end up with

```
[
  { id: "a", priority: 1 },
  { id: "b", priority: 2 },
  { id: "d", priority: 3 },
  { id: "c", priority: 4 }
]
```

This will of course also work for any other modification of priority.

Comment: he basically want to swap priority and no one can have same priority

Comment: @FahadTahir Yes - this technique will work fine for that too.

Comment: Interesting approach, will try to work with this. Thanks, will mark as answered after testing.

Answer (score 0):

You could exploit array indices to reorder your priorities! The below code moves things around so that the items are in an array (sorted by priority, but without an actual `priority` field), then just moves around the items in the list and restores the field:

```js
const setPriority = (items, id, priority) => {
  const _items = [...items].sort(byPriority)
  const index = _items.findIndex(x => x.id === id)
  const stripped = stripPriorities(_items)
  moveItem(stripped, index, priority - 1)
  return restorePriorities(stripped)
}

const moveItem = (arr, oldIndex, newIndex) => {
  const temp = arr.splice(oldIndex, 1)[0]
  arr.splice(newIndex, 0, temp)
}

const stripPriorities = arr =>
  arr.map(({ priority, ...x }) => x)
  
const restorePriorities = arr =>
  arr.map((x, i) => ({ ...x, priority: i + 1 }))
  
const byPriority = (x, y) =>
  x.priority > y.priority
```

Here's a working demo: https://jsfiddle.net/kadft7ep/3/

Comment: Hi Isaac, Thanks for taking your time. Your solution is a bit more complicated than AKX, not sure performance impact of either but will keep this in mind to test for future use

Comment: No problem! I initially thought the problem was a lot simpler than it actually was, and then when it wasn't I was intrigued so I had to solve it lol. In any case, I'll be keeping this method in my back pocket for if I need it in the future.

Answer (score 0):

### Increase Priority by 1

Your objects

```
let data = [{id: 1, priority: 1}, {id: 2, priority: 2}, {id: 3, priority: 3}]
```

Object to whome you want to increase priority by 1
lets say id=2
first find the object, i am assuming you found it in let obj.
now

```
obj.priority-=1.5
// resulting data will be [{id: 1, priority: 1}, {id: 2, priority: 0.5}, {id: 3, priority: 3}]
```

after sorting data would look something like

```
[{id: 2, priority: 0.5}, {id: 1, priority: 1}, {id: 3, priority: 3}]
```

now the same approach to make them as whole numbers

```
data = data.map((obj, index) => {
  obj.priority = index + 1;
});
// result [{id: 2, priority: 1}, {id: 1, priority: 2}, {id: 3, priority: 3}]
```

### Make Most Prioritize

Instead of -1.5 just make priority 0 & then sort & then whole numbers again